# MySQL and Coldfusion date issue

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I have a `timestamp` field in a MySQL table. I am trying to query the table using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  login_mode,count(login_mode) as total 
FROM    login_activity,ccac_registered_users 
WHERE   login_activity.student_id=ccac_registered_users.student_id 
AND     login_date >= STR_TO_DATE('01/16/2013','%m/%d/%Y') 
AND     login_date <= STR_TO_DATE('01/17/2013','%m/%d/%Y') 
GROUP BY login_mode
```

The query works fine when I run it on Mysql directly, but doesn't work from the coldfusion app. I am stumped! The code to generate the dates is :

```
login_date >= STR_TO_DATE(
                 '#DateFormat(CreateODBCDate(startDate),'mm/dd/yyyy')#'
                 , '%m/%d/%Y'
              )
```

And the error from ColdFusion is this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '01/16/2013'',''%m/%d/%Y'') AND login_date <=
>   STR_TO_DATE(''01/17/2013'',''%m/%d/' at line 1

What is wrong here?

**Edit**

I just dumped the sql that CF is trying to execute.

```
SELECT login_mode,count(login_mode) as total 
FROM   login_activity,ccac_registered_users 
WHERE  login_activity.student_id=ccac_registered_users.student_id 
AND    login_date >= STR_TO_DATE(''01/16/2013'',''%m/%d/%Y'') 
AND    login_date <= STR_TO_DATE(''01/17/2013'',''%m/%d/%Y'')
```

There are additional quotes around the date and they are causing the issue. If I remove the extra ones I have added from the code, then nothing gets added.

Comment: @Leigh The quote isn't missing. It is at the end of the paranthesis. I will try using just CreateODBCDate. AFAIK, it wasn't working with mysql when i tries last.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. My eyes missed a quote.

Comment: You might also want to look into using BETWEEN in your query.

Comment: Depends on the desired results and the data itself. If any of the contain a "time" portion (very likely), then `between` and the original query would only match up records *dated* on between January 16 at midnight through January 17th at midnight. All other *times* on the 17th would be excluded. To include all times on the 17th, use `WHERE col >= {startDateAtMidnight} AND col < {dayAfterEndDateAtMidnight}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFQUERY likes to automatically escape single quotes. To get it to work the way you've written it, you'll need to wrap things in `preserveSingleQuotes()` to prevent CF from adding the extra single quotes. Or rewrite it using one of the other suggestions for date comparisons.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used MySQL, but if you can pass arguments to a function using double quotes, that would avoid the problem altogether:

`STR_TO_DATE("#DateFormat(CreateODBCDate(startDate),'mm/dd/yyyy')#","%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: The query is being formed dynamically and it is already enclosed in double quotes, hence using single quotes.

Comment: **Please do not** recommend using `preserveSingleQuotes` without mentioning it completely undoes the automatic protection CF adds and exposes your database to sql injection. Do not use it unless you know what you are getting into and have thoroughly scrubbed your data.

Answer (score 7):

(From my earlier comment ...)

There should be absolutely no need to use `dateFormat` or `str_to_date`. `DateFormat` is designed for presentation and returns a *string*. What you should be using is a date object. `CreateODBCDate` already gives you that. So just use it directly in your query. (Obviously you should always validate the input first)

```
 WHERE column >= #CreateODBCDate(startDate)#  
 ....
```

.. or better yet, use cfqueryparam:

```
 WHERE column >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#startDate#">
```

Answer (score 4):

Use queryparameters and dateobjects instead of strings.  Like this:

```
AND login_date >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#CreateDate(2013,1,16)#"> 
AND login_date <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#CreateDate(2013,1,17)#">
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using DateDIff to perform date comparaisons instead of comparing date in string, work really well for 4 of my apps

details here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: I disagree.  Using functions in the where clause often makes queries run slower.  This would be especially true if the field in question was indexed.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL use:

```
    CONVERT(DateTime, DateField, 104)
```

or try:

```
    CAST( right(@date,4) + left(@date,4) as datetime )
```

I thought the ColdFusion equivalent was:

```
    <cfset date = DateFormat(date, "mm/dd/yyyy")>
```

-- no?

Comment: DateFormat does not work on a string, in needs a date/time object.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh - It is designed for *dates* yes. But as with most date functions in CF it will readily accept a "parseable" date string as well. Note, it is always interpreted as a U.S. date string.